# Using adjectives to denote possession

Tags: adjectives, possessive

I think I saw this in another post, but I can't find it now...

Can you use adjectives to denote possession?  I was reading this [cute Christmas story](http://esperantaretradio.blogspot.com/2016/12/kristnaska-fabelo-de-tuomo-grundstrom.html) and saw this usage:

> En la patrina koro

and this:

> en la patraj okuloj

The only way I can understand this is as "in the mother's heart..." and "in the father's eyes".  Is this correct?  Is this common, or just a very poetic turn of phrase?

Answer (score 7):

*En la patrina koro* means *in the motherly heart*. The heart has a motherly quality. However, we don't know who owns the heart. Even though I am a man, I could have a motherly heart.

*En la koro de patrino* means *in the heart of a mother*.

#### La koro de la ŝtono batas

[image]
<sub>(source: [splicedwire.com](http://splicedwire.com/05reviews/fantastic4.jpg))</sub>

#### La ŝtona koro ne batas

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no you don't use adjectives to denote possession. Words like *mia, lia, ilia* etc. look like adjectives, but they're not.

*Patrina brusto* clearly means mother's chest in the same way that patrina lakto is a mother's milk - a kind of milk, not necessarily milk belonging to the mother (although in this case it's clear that we're talking about the boy's mother's chest.)

You'll occasionally see someone turn a proper name into an adjective to the same effect. It's not very common, though.