# Proper names + a

Tags: adjectives

I have been wondering about the word *Zamenhofa* (e.g., [here](http://tekstaro.com/) or [here](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamenhofa_Tago)). I am very sure it is the only proper name I have seen converted to an adjective with an *-a* ending – but then again I haven't seen that much yet. Is this just another form of a possessive? Would I be understood (or, if the answer to the previous is "no", what would that mean), if I said, e.g., *Tomasa*? Or is perhaps L. Zamenhof the only one whose *-a* form entered a wide usage?

Comment: Mi certe ne pensas ke estas la sama demando. Cxi tiu demando neniel temas pri posedado. Zamenhof ne posedas la zamenhofan tagon.

Comment: I have the impression the question is about the meaning of a proper name + a. It is not about how to build a "possesive" specifically. Other users should be able to add other less specific answers.

Comment: The linked question has possessives in name but I agreed that the answers applied here. It probably does not make too much difference whether it's "patrina koro" or "Zamenhofa koro".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This came up under this question here: [Using adjectives to denote possession](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/using-adjectives-to-denote-possession/2544#2544)

I've certainly seen people use *Tomasa* as something like a possessive. Keep in mind, though, that *Zamenhofa* doesn't mean "belonging to Zamenhof" but rather "related to Zamenhof" - perhaps "Zamenhofian."

Comment: Thank you! I actually had seen that question earlier but did not realize just how relevant its *answers* were here. I wonder why they'd say "Zamenhofaj tekstoj", though.

Comment: Zamenhofian texts. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is already a nice suffix '-es'
So why don't we utilize it?

- "libroj de Zamenhof"

tio cxi estas la standarda uzo, sed gxia vico ne kongruas al iuj naciaj pensmanieroj- ekzemple mi estas cxinlingva parolanto mi ne tre preferas tion cxar gxi maltauxgas por mia natura penso;

- "Zamenhof-es libroj" (mia stilo ;)

mi inzistas la uzon (mi malofte vidas tion en Esperantujo, sed laux principalo de Esperanto, kial ne ni provu?)

- "Zamenhof-aj libroj"

  hm mi pensas ke gxi kauxzos miskomprenojn: cxu la libro apartenas al Zamenhof aux cxu la libro havas Zamenhof-es karakterojn?

Comment: The -es you mention is not a suffix.  It's one of the parts of the system of correlatives.

The possessive in Esperanto for pronouns is formed with -a (lia, nia, ilia), and with nouns by "de" (la libro de Miko".

"Zamenhofaj libroj" would be books by or about Zamenhof, but not Zamenhof's books.

Comment: "Zamenhofaj libroj" would be books by or about Zamenhof, but not Zamenhof's books- konziderante tion cxi, "-a" ne plu esprimas posedecon se gxi estas je fino de iu nomo.